# Alternative to File.AppendAllText for newline

Tags: c#, file, append, text-files

I am trying to read characters from a file and then append them in another file after removing the comments (which are followed by semicolon).

sample data from parent file:

```
           Name- Harly Brown             ;Name is Harley Brown

           Age- 20                  ;Age is 20 years
```

Desired result:

```
           Name- Harley Brown

           Age- 20
```

I am trying the following code-

```
        StreamReader infile = new StreamReader(floc + "G" + line + ".NC0");
        while (infile.Peek() != -1)
        {
            letter = Convert.ToChar(infile.Read());
            if (letter == ';')
            {
                infile.ReadLine();
            }

            else
            {

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, Convert.ToString(letter));

            }
         }
```

But the output i am getting is-

```
            Name- Harley Brown  Age-20
```

Its because AppendAllText is not working for the newline. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why not use `File.AppendAllLines`. See documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Appends lines to a file, and then closes the file. If the specified file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified lines to the file, and then closes the file.

It takes in any `IEnumerable<string>` and adds every line to the specified file. So it always adds the line on a new line.

Small example:

```
const string originalFile = @"D:\Temp\file.txt";
const string newFile = @"D:\Temp\newFile.txt";

// Retrieve all lines from the file.
string[] linesFromFile = File.ReadAllLines(originalFile); 

List<string> linesToAppend = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in linesFromFile)
{
    // 1. Split the line at the semicolon.
    // 2. Take the first index, because the first part is your required result.
    // 3. Trim the trailing and leading spaces.
    string appendAbleLine = line.Split(';').FirstOrDefault().Trim();

    // Add the line to the list of lines to append.
    linesToAppend.Add(appendAbleLine);
}

// Append all lines to the file.
File.AppendAllLines(newFile, linesToAppend);
```

Output:

> Name- Harley Brown
>   Age- 20

You could even change the foreach-loop into a LINQ-expression, if you prefer LINQ:

```
List<string> linesToAppend = linesFromFile.Select(line => line.Split(';').FirstOrDefault().Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Matthijis. But i am a newbie and I ll have to study a little about the IEnumerable<string>. 
But here in this example, two different lines are appended while I am reading a complete text file in a go and then expecting the program to read "\r\n" and automatically add a newline..
Should i read each line in the parent file and then write..??

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with LINQ, [`System.File.ReadLines(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`System.File.WriteAllLines(string, IEnumerable<string>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx). You could also use [`System.File.AppendAllLines(string, IEnumerable<string>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx) in a find-and-replace fashion if that was, in fact, the functionality you were going for. The difference, as the names suggest, is whether it writes everything out as a new file or if it just appends to an existing one.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(newPath, System.IO.File.ReadLines(oldPath).Select(c =>
                   {
                       int semicolon = c.IndexOf(';');

                       if (semicolon > -1)
                           return c.Remove(semicolon);
                       else
                           return c;
                   }));
```

In case you aren't super familiar with LINQ syntax, the idea here is to loop through each line in the file, and if it contains a semicolon (that is, `IndexOf` returns something that is over -1) we cut that off, and otherwise, we just return the string. Then we write all of those to the file. The `StreamReader` equivalent to this would be:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(oldPath))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newPath))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       int semicolon = line.IndexOf(';');

       if (semicolon > -1)
           line = c.Remove(semicolon);

       writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Although, of course, this would feed an extra empty line at the end and the LINQ version wouldn't (as far as I know, it occurs to me that I'm not one hundred percent sure on that, but if someone reading this does know I would appreciate a comment).

Another important thing to note, just looking at your original file, you might want to add in some `Trim` calls, since it looks like you can have spaces before your semicolons, and I don't imagine you want those copied through.

Answer (score 0):

Why use char by char comparison when .NET Framework is full of useful string manipulation functions?

Also, don't use a file write function multiple times when you can use it only one time, it's time and resources consuming!

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader("file1.txt");
string       str    = "";

while ((string line = infile.ReadLine()) != null) { // Get every line of the file.
    line = line.Split(';')[0].Trim();               // Remove comment (right part of ;) and useless white characters.
    str += line + "\n";                             // Add it to our final file contents.
}

File.WriteAllText("file2.txt", str); // Write it to the new file.
```

Comment: What about `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @Zigma +1. Particularly since we're working on Windows machines with C#, so a line break is actually carriage return followed by a line feed (`\r\n`), not just a line feed.

Comment: @Xatrix. thank you very much, i didnt knw about the .split and .trim commands. But unfortunately the result is still the same..